# What would be a good way to select one class or another class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select one class that is created dynamically, or another class that is created in html. What would be a good way of doing this?

I've tried this:

```
$('.wrapper' || '.surround').on('click', '.bet-button', function(){}
```

and also this:

```
$('.wrapper', '.surround').on('click', '.bet-button', function(){}
```

is there a way to write this, so far it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You should also add the missing `)` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

**You're almost there:**

*Only separate them with comma*

```
$('.wrapper, .surround').on('click', '.bet-button', function(){}
```

Comment: Can you explain how that make sense, why would I wan the comma to be inside of the quotations? Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Bkes because that's how selectors work. It's the same as in CSS. If you put the comma inside the String, you're passing it to jQuery. Otherwise, you're calling `$(a, b)` which evaluates to `$(b)` (Javascript comma operator)

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! Had a moment there haha

Comment: @Bkes Chris has already explained `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
$('.wrapper, .surround').on('click', '.bet-button', function(){}
```